# How can I add a type constraint to include anything serializable in a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, attributes, serializable

My generic method needs to serialize the object passed to it, however just insisting that it implements ISerializable doesn't seem to work. For example, I have a struct returned from a web service (marked with SerializableAttribute) that serializes to xml just fine, but, as expected, the C# compiler complains.

Is there a way I can check the object is serializable before attempting to serialize it, or, better still, a way of using the `where` keyword to check the object is suitable?

Here's my full method:

```
public static void Push<T>(string url, T message)
        where T : ISerializable
{
    string xml = SerializeMessage(message);

    // Send the message to Amazon SQS
    SendMessageRequest sendReq = new SendMessageRequest { QueueUrl = url, MessageBody = xml };
    AmazonSQSClient client = new AmazonSQSClient(S3User, S3Pass);
    client.SendMessage(sendReq);
}
```

And SerializeMessage:

```
private static string SerializeMessage<T>(T message)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, message);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

If this isn't possible, what's the best way to perform a check that an object is serializable at runtime?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can't do this totally via generic constraints, but you can do a couple things to help:

1) Put the **new()** constraint on the generic type (to enable the ability to deserialize and to ensure the XmlSerializer doesn't complain about a lack of default ctor):

```
where T : new()
```

2) On the first line of your method handling the serialization (or constructor or anywhere else you don't have to repeat it over and over), you can perform this check:

```
if( !typeof(T).IsSerializable && !(typeof(ISerializable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) ) )
    throw new InvalidOperationException("A serializable Type is required");
```

Of course, there's still the possibility of runtime exceptions when trying to serialize a type, but this will cover the most obvious issues.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as it will give false positives. typeof(T) evaluates to System.Runtime.Type, which is ISerializable, so it will always evaluate to true. Use this instead...  if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable && !(typeof(ISerializable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))))

Comment: where T : new() excludes System.Tuple<> which are marked with   the Serializable attribute.

Comment: True, but that still seems pretty safe. Most people don't even know what a tuple is, let alone that there's a .NET Tuple<T1.....T7> class. Plus, Tuple will only serialize with binary serialization anyway (no XML) because it doesn't have a default ctor.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a length blog article on this subject that you may find helpful.  It mainly goes into binary serialization but the concepts are applicable to most any serialization format.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/03/31/is-it-serializable.aspx

The long and short of it is

- There is no way to add a reliable generic constraint
- The only way to check and see if an object **was** serializable is to serialize it and see if the operation succeeds

Comment: Is this still the state of the art?  With static interfaces and all?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know if an object is serializable is to try to serialize it.

In fact, you were asking how to tell if a type "is serializable", but the actual question will be with respect to objects. Some instances of a type may not be serializable even if the type is marked [Serializable]. For instance, what if the instance contains circular references?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

try

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(message.GetType());

Answer (score 0):

C# 8 and up allows the `unmanaged` constraint to limit types to structs that have nothing but value types in them (on any nested level). What we really want is:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : ISerializable or unmanaged
```

But unfortunately, at the time of writing C# does not support this syntax (constraints are always AND, separated by commas).

A workaround could be a ValueWrapper class:

```
public class ValueWrapper<U> : ISerializable where U : unmanaged
```

This takes a U for a constructor argument. It has one property `U Value`. Now you can treat value types as ISerializable simply by wrapping them in a ValueWrapper.