# Is it possible to get Class attributes? C#

Tags: c#

I have a class which is using generics. This class do some operation which need serialization. So the class which will be given to myClass must hold the attribute [Serializable()]. Is it possible to request a class which attributes it holds? In best case at design time.

```
    [Serializable()]
    public class clsSchnappschuss<T>
    {
      //Some operations which need serialization
    }
```

So if someone uses clsSchnappschuss he must give the DataType (T) and i want to request that T implements [Serializable()]. Is this possible?

regards

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226161/test-if-a-class-has-an-attribute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945495/how-can-i-add-a-type-constraint-to-include-anything-serializable-in-a-generic-me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot request a presence of an attribute statically (i.e. at compile time), but inside the code your generic type you can examine `T` as if it were an actual type name. For example, you can request its `typeof`, and pull attributes from it:

```
public class clsSchnappschuss<T> {
    static clsSchnappschuss() {
        if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), typeof(SerializableAttribute)) == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(typeof(T).FullName +" is not serializable.");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I put the check in a static constructor. This would execute once before any other code that uses `clsSchnappschuss<>` for each particular type.

Comment: I was just about to write exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

if your given classes implement the ISerializeable interface you could to following:

```
public class clsSchnappschuss<T> where T : ISerializable
```